# Unable to write file on Android 11 - FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I've read all the relevant questions and answers, but I still can not open a file for writing with `FileOutputStream`. When I call
`FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newpathandfilename);`
It throws a `FileNotFoundException`
What I did so far:
AndroidManifest.xml has:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
```

Also application tag has `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` set to true.
At runtime I check the permission:

```
private void showExplanation(String title,
                             String message,
                             final String permission,
                             final int permissionRequestCode) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());
    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    requestPermission(permission, permissionRequestCode);
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
}

private void requestPermission(String permissionName, int permissionRequestCode) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(),
            new String[]{permissionName}, permissionRequestCode);
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {

            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Then:

```
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("Granted","Granted");
        } else {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this.getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                showExplanation("Permission required", "Permission required", Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 1);
            } else {
                requestPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 1);
            }
        }
```

It writes the access is granted already.
The path is `/storage/emulated/0/myApp/NewFile20220520_222112.jpg`.
The exception is: `open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`
compileSdkVersion 30
targetSdkVersion 30
Device: API level 30
Any idea what is missing?

Comment: You do not have write access to arbitrary locations on the filesystem anymore. Use app-specific storage (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`) to get a directory that you can write into.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. What made me wondering that reading is allowed, but writing is not. Now I replaced `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` with `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` and it works.